# join 2 tables using a pivot

Tags: mysql, join, pivot-table

can anyone please help me with this...

So I have two tables.

**user_info**(username,firstname,lastname,address)
AND 
**user_contact**(username,number,primary,alternate)

example fields in user_contacts 
('abc',xxx-xxx-xxxx,1,0) 
('abc',xxx-xxx-xxxx,0,1) 
('abc',xxx-xxx-xxxx,0,1) 
('abc',xxx-xxx-xxxx,0,1) 
('def',xxx-xxx-xxxx,1,0) 
('def',xxx-xxx-xxxx,0,1) 
('def',xxx-xxx-xxxx,0,1)

this means that the user can have more than one alternate phone numbers.

what i want to do is join the two tables, and get the result like,  
**(username,primary number, alternate num1, alternate num2, alternate num3 .. )**

What I have so far is this, but this can give me only 1 alternate number and not all.

```
select username,firstname,lastname,address,
       sum(if(c.primary=1,c.number,NULL) as primary,
       sum(if(c.alternate=1,c.number,NULL) as alternate
from user_info as i left join
     user_contact as c
     on i.username = c.username
group by username
```

I will appreciate the help a lot. I read into pivote tables, but im unable to find something that answers my doubts.

Thanks in adv

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array)

Comment: I agree, I did it using PHP , but I am required to use MySQL to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who tried to solve this for me.
I figured out the answer to it. If you are curious, it goes this way

```
select username, firstname,lastname,address,
 max(if(uc.`primary`=1 AND uc.row_num=1, uc.number,0)) as phone,
 max(if(uc.row_num=2, uc.number,0)) as alt1,
 max(if(uc.row_num=3, uc.number,0)) as alt2,
 max(if(uc.row_num=4, uc.number,0)) as alt3,
 max(if(uc.row_num=5, uc.number,0)) as alt4
from user_info as ui
left join 
(
 Select username, number,`primary`,alternate, 
    if(@type = username,@rowNum:=@rowNum+1,@rowNum:=1) as row_num,
    @type := username as `type`
 from user_contact , (select @rowNum:=0 , @type:='') as r
 group by username, number
 order by username, `primary` desc
) as uc 
on ui.username = uc.username
order by username
```